# Laravel 8.52 application unable to load application(page not found) without appending index.php/ infront of the url

Tags: laravel, apache

I am running on Laravel 8.52 application. Web is hosted by Apache 2.4.41. the folder directory of my web root is /var/www/new.com/html

```
drwxrwxr-x  8 www-data www-data   4096 Feb  2 19:24 assets
drwxrwxr-x 12 www-data www-data   4096 Feb  7 15:39 core
-rwxrwxr-x  1 www-data www-data   1739 Feb  2 19:25 index.php
```

core is the folder that housed my laravel application. index.php is the laravel index file.

```
/var/www/new.com/html/core$ ls -la
total 960
drwxrwxr-x 12 www-data www-data   4096 Feb  7 15:39 .
drwxrwxr-x  6 www-data www-data   4096 Feb  7 20:08 ..
drwxrwxr-x 10 www-data www-data   4096 Feb  2 19:24 app
-rwxrwxr-x  1 www-data www-data   1686 Feb  2 19:24 artisan
drwxrwxr-x  3 www-data www-data   4096 Feb  2 19:24 bootstrap
-rwxrwxr-x  1 www-data www-data   2335 Feb  2 19:24 composer.json
-rwxrwxr-x  1 www-data www-data 355511 Feb  2 19:24 composer.lock
drwxrwxr-x  2 www-data www-data   4096 Feb  2 19:24 config
drwxrwxr-x  5 www-data www-data   4096 Feb  2 19:24 database
-rwxrwxr-x  1 www-data www-data    220 Feb  2 19:45 .editorconfig
-rwxrwxr-x  1 www-data www-data    977 Feb  6 23:51 .env
-rwxrwxr-x  1 www-data www-data    111 Feb  2 19:24 .gitattributes
-rwxrwxr-x  1 www-data www-data    191 Feb  2 19:24 .gitignore
-rwxrwxr-x  1 www-data www-data    707 Feb  7 00:07 .htaccess
-rwxrwxr-x  1 www-data www-data    730 Feb  2 19:24 package.json
-rwxrwxr-x  1 www-data www-data 521192 Feb  2 19:24 package-lock.json
-rwxrwxr-x  1 www-data www-data   1202 Feb  2 19:24 phpunit.xml
drwxrwxr-x  2 www-data www-data   4096 Feb  6 23:12 public
-rwxrwxr-x  1 www-data www-data   3780 Feb  2 19:24 README.md
drwxrwxr-x  4 www-data www-data   4096 Feb  2 19:24 resources
drwxrwxr-x  2 www-data www-data   4096 Feb  2 19:24 routes
-rwxrwxr-x  1 www-data www-data    563 Feb  7 15:39 server.php
drwxrwxr-x  6 www-data www-data   4096 Feb  2 19:24 storage
-rwxrwxr-x  1 www-data www-data    181 Feb  2 19:24 .styleci.yml
drwxrwxr-x  4 www-data www-data   4096 Feb  2 19:24 tests
drwxrwxr-x 49 www-data www-data   4096 Feb  2 19:25 vendor
-rwxrwxr-x  1 www-data www-data    549 Feb  2 19:24 webpack.mix.js
```

my apache virtual host config is

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
        <VirtualHost _default_:443>
                ServerAdmin webmaster@new.com
                ServerName  new.com
                ServerAlias www.new.com
                DocumentRoot /var/www/new.com/html
                DirectoryIndex index.php

                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

                SSLEngine on

                SSLCertificateFile      /etc/ssl/certs/www.new.com.crt
                SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/www.new.com.key

                <Directory "/var/www/new.com/html">
                        Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                        Order Allow,Deny
                        Allow from all
                </Directory>


                <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
                </FilesMatch>
                <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
                </Directory>
        </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

and i dont use .htaccess on the web root folder.

the problem is, I can load the domain successfully. e.g https://www.new.com

but there is a laravel app called admin can't loaded through https://www.new.com/admin
it returned page not found, The requested URL was not found on this server.

However, it can loaded successfully, if I enter https://www.new.com/index.php/admin

so how do I go about fixing it, without additionally enter the /index.php/
Thanks.
Cheers.

I have tried configuring .htaccess at the web root folder, but none of the parameters that i tested work.

I have tried remove the virtual host config and use /var/www/html as the web root folder instead.
I have tried just the port 80 only.

Not of the above the method works. It should be clear that the problem could be lie with laravel and not apache2.

here is my index.php at the webroot.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Check If Application Is Under Maintenance
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| If the application is maintenance / demo mode via the "down" command we
| will require this file so that any prerendered template can be shown
| instead of starting the framework, which could cause an exception.
|
*/

if (file_exists(__DIR__.'/core/storage/framework/maintenance.php')) {
    require __DIR__.'/core/storage/framework/maintenance.php';
}

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register The Auto Loader
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class loader for
| this application. We just need to utilize it! We'll simply require it
| into the script here so we don't need to manually load our classes.
|
*/

require __DIR__.'/core/vendor/autoload.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Run The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Once we have the application, we can handle the incoming request using
| the application's HTTP kernel. Then, we will send the response back
| to this client's browser, allowing them to enjoy our application.
|
*/

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/core/bootstrap/app.php';

$kernel = $app->make(Kernel::class);

$response = tap($kernel->handle(
```

Comment: Your `public/.htaccess` file is being ignored; ensure mod_rewrite is installed and permitted in that directory, or move those rules into your VirtualHost config.

Comment: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>
    RewriteEngine On
    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>

Comment: @ceejayoz, here is the content of my public/.htaccess,  it is default config. the mod rewrite is configured by default. you think I should move these rules to virtualhost config?

Comment: Your `.htaccess` is default config, but it's not working. The problem isn't *in* the `.htaccess` file. You can move the rules, or you can permit `.htaccess` to function with something like an `AllowOverride all` setting in the main config.

Comment: @ceejayoz, I am assuming your mentioned of main config referring to /etc/apache2/apache2.conf right? let me give it a try now.

Comment: <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride none
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/new.com/html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all
        Require all granted
</Directory>
/etc/apache2/apache2.conf here is the content, but it doesn't work still

Comment: No luck after I tried it on /etc/apache2/apache2.conf  with AllowOverride all on my web root. <Directory /var/www/new.com/html>

Comment: I'd be checking if mod_rewrite is properly enabled, then.

Comment: @ceejayoz, i did check with sudo a2enmod rewrite and restarted the apache2 service. no luck still, i believe this is what you mean by mod_rewrite enable, right?